# context.xml duplicate attribute uses with the same name and target namespace

Tags: xml, spring, eclipse

**Summary:**

I've open a project I've rolled onto with eclipse and there is a file called ibatisServicesApplicationContext.xml. I've already cleaned up a couple of errors that eclipse reported as problems with it.

Now I'm seeing 5 errors related to `#AnonType_array`, `#AnonType_list`, `#AnonType_set`, `#AnonType_map`, and `#AnonType_props` being duplicate attributes for a name space.

One of the specific errors is: `ct-props-correct.4: Error for type '#AnonType_array'. Duplicate attribute uses with the same name and target namespace are specified. Name of duplicate attribute use is 'merge'.`

Doing some googling and reading, errors like this have shown up when mixing version. Reference: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/68894-errors-when-validating-spring-beans-2-5-xsd-from-sts and https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/spring-beans-3-0-xsd-validation-errors/

Looking at the references, it looks like the references are legit. Any idea on what's wrong with the config?

**Details:**

The following is the top of my file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
    xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
    xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
    xmlns:drools="http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring"
    xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring 
        drools-spring-1.2.0.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration 
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/core 
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd
        http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring 
        ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security 
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd">
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Posting details of what fixed things for me, in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

One of the problems I resolved was the fact that `drools-spring-1.2.0.xsd` wasn't hosted anymore, so I found an archived version of it and added it to the project to reference locally. Inside of that file is a reference to `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd` which is where the conflict is occurring.

Looking at drools, all of the xsds through version 1.7.0 all reference 2.0.xsd, so changed the 3.0 references to 2.0 and project no longer complains.